# How to enable openGL calls tracing in cpp application?

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing a simple c++ opengl/gles application. Is here any easy way to trace gl calls?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debugging_Tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal favorite tool (so far) is [APItrace](https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace). It allows you to trace your applications gl calls, and play them back, inspecting the current state of your context.
An alternative would be [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/), a more complex tool, visualizing attributes and varyings, and giving you more options then APItrace.

If none of these tools suit your needs check the [OpenGL-Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debugging_Tools) for more :)